# Send Captured Image to another view with prepareforSgue

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

So when I press captured button, it's taking a photo and I can save the image in my camera roll. But when I want to see image in another view I can't see it.

This is my code :

```
- (IBAction)captureButton:(id)sender
{
    [self.cameraViewController captureImageWithCompletionHander:^(id data) {
        self.image = ([data isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) ? [UIImage imageWithData:data] : data;
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.image, nil, nil, nil);
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"savingSegue" sender:self];
    }];
}
```

And this is the prepare for segue method.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"savingSegue"]) {
        PhotoSaveViewController *pvc = [[PhotoSaveViewController alloc] init];
        [pvc.imageView setImage:self.image];
    }
}
```

Comment: `PhotoSaveViewController *pvc = segue.destinationViewController` instead of the alloc/init.

Comment: its crashing the app 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController imageView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: You have to show your storyboard. How is presented `PhotoSaveViewController`? It seems to have a NavigationController. So `segue.destinationViewController` is a `UINavigationController`. So get the VC from it.

Comment: Have a look at this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/28661950/4038509.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your destination view controller is a `UINavigationController`. I'm guessing its top view controller is the one you want. You can access it like this (though you may wish to add type checking):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"savingSegue"]) {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        PhotoSaveViewController *pvc = (PhotoSaveViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
        [pvc.imageView setImage:self.image];
    }
}
```

Comment: No,I have a modal segue and cameraviewcontroller is mine initial view.So I need the send the picture to the PhotoSaveViewController for looking on it

Comment: Have you tried the code above? If it doesn't work then we will need to see your storyboard.

Comment: Yes I tried.And It's not show anything too.http://prntscr.com/7dezg3 that is my storyboard

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
 if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"savingSegue"])
 {
    YourNextViewController*ImageView=segue.destinationViewController;
    UIImage*clickedImage=capturedPicImageView.image;
   ImageView.passedImage=clickedImage;
    // NSLog(@"%@",editView.editPhotoImgView.image);
 }
}
```

(And in YourNextViewController create `UIImage*clickedImage` and give property to it. and        dont forget to allocate in viewDidLoad. Hope this helps.